# Chaining promises with mongoose (mPromises)

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, promise, chain

I'm looking for advice on how to chain promises for a "fin or create" feature using nodejs/mongoose(mPromise)

I've currently tried:

```js
var findExistingUsername = function(value){
 console.log('existusername');
  return mongoose.models["User"].findOne({username: value})
   .lean()
   .exec();
};

var findExistingEmail= function(value){
 console.log('existusername');
  return mongoose.models["User"].findOne({email: value})
   .lean()
   .exec();
};

var validateEmail = function(value){
 console.log('existusername');
  var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    console.log('Email valido?:' + emailRegex.test(email));
    return emailRegex.test(email);
};

var addUser = function(data){
 console.log('existusername');
  return mongoose.models["User"].create(data);
};


UserSchema.methods = {

validateAndAddUser: function(req, res) {

 return findExistingUsername(this.username)
   .then(function(existingUser){
    if(existingUser)
     throw 'El nombre de usuario ya está cogido.'
   })
   .chain(findExistingEmail(this.email))
   .then(function(existingEmail){
    if(existingEmail)
     throw 'El correo electrónico ya está registrado.'
   })
   .chain(addUser(this))
   .then(function(){
       console.log('user creado con exito.');        
      })
      .onResolve(function(){
       console.log('success');
       res.status(200).json({
               payload: 'user',
               message: "Cuenta creada con éxito"});
      })
      .onReject(function(err){
       console.log('err');
       res.status(400).json({
             payload: err.code,
             message: err});
      });
}};
```

And call it from my (node/express) API endpoint:

```js
exports.createUser = function (req, res) {
    var newUser = new UserModel(req.body);
 // Promise
 newUser.validateAndAddUser(req, res).fulfill();
};
```

Problems:

1) I'm not sure I'm using the right promise style/most efficient coding style.

2) TypeError: Object # has no method 'chain'.

Im using this:

-mongoose@3.8.17

-https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise

-https://nadeesha.silvrback.com/a-quick-intro-to-mpromise-in-mongoose

Can anyone see what Im doing wrong, and how i could do it better?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't throw strings. Also you're calling `chain` instead of `then` at one point.

Comment: Also so you're calling `then` with a promise as the argument, not a function.